# Understanding Correlation Between Columns Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, statistics, correlation

I have a dataset with daily sales of two products for the first 10 days of their release. The dataframe below shows a single and dozens of items being sold per day for each product. Its believed that no dozens product was sold before a single item of the product had been sold. The two products (Period_ID) has expected number of dozens sale.

```
d = {'Period_ID':['A12']*10, 'Prod_A_Doz':[1.2]*10, 'Prod_B_Doz':[2.4]*10, 'A_Singles':[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4], 'B_Singles':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
     'A_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1], 'B_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**QUESTION**

I want to construct a descriptive analysis in which one of my questions is to figure out how many single items of each product sold in average before a dozen was sold the 1st time, 2nd time,..., 10th time?

Given that    `df.Period_ID.nunique() = 1568`

**Modifying** the dataset for sales per day as oppose to the above cumulative sales and using `Pankaj Joshi` solution with small alteration,

```
print(f'Average number of single items before {index + 1} dozen = {df1.A_Singles[:val+1].mean():0.2f}')


d = {'Period_ID':['A12']*10, 'Prob_A_Doz':[1.2]*10, 'Prod_B_Doz':[2.4]*10, 'A_Singles':[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'B_Singles':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
 'A_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], 'B_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# For product A
Average number of single items before 1 dozen = 0.38

# For product B
6
Average number of single items before 1 dozen = 0.43
8
Average number of single items before 2 dozen = 0.44, But I want this to be counted from the last Dozens of sales. so rather 0.44, it should be 0.5
```

The aim is once I have the information for each `Period_ID` then i will take the average for all df.Period_ID.nunique() (= 1568) and try to optimise the expected number of 'Dozens' sale for each product given under the col Prod_A_Doz and Prod_B_Doz

I would appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
d = {'Period_ID':['A12']*10, 'Prob_A_Doz':[1.2]*10, 'Prod_B_Doz':[2.4]*10, 'A_Singles':[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4], 'B_Singles':[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
 'A_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1], 'B_Dozens':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


for per_id in set(df1.Period_ID):
    print(per_id)

    df_temp = df1[df1.Period_ID == per_id]
    for index, val in enumerate(df_temp.index[df_temp.A_Dozens>0]):
        print(val)
        print(f'Average number of single items before {index} dozen = {df_temp.A_Singles[:val].mean():0.2f}')
        print(f'Average number of single items before {index} dozen = {df_temp.B_Dozens[:val].mean():0.2f}')
```

Comment: (val+1) works well for the above data. Now how can I obtain the mean for all 1568 df.Period_ID?

Comment: Just by putting the code in a for loop. I modified the code above.